# Proof that Henkin extension by constants is conservative over intuitionistic theories

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In fact I'm interested in a (preferably constructive) proof of the meta-implication:
$T\vdash[\exists x B(x)\to B(c)]\to A $
implies
$T\vdash A $
, where
$c$ is a new constant for $T, B$ and $A$ and the proof system in hand is intuitionistic Natural Deduction.

Just to note, I cannot use $(B\to A)\leftrightarrow (\neg B\vee A)$ nor the prenex operations as in standard proofs for classical theories.

Comment: Are you saying that you want an intuitionistic proof that classical theories satisfy the rule, a classical proof that intuitionistic theories satisfy the rule, or an intuitionistic proof that intuitionistic theories satisfy the rule? The usual proof that classical theories satisfy the rule is completely constructive: it turns a proof of $[\exists x B(x) \to B(c)] \to A$ into a proof of $A$ directly by manipulating the proof.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that ambiguity. I want the third option - let's assume, that the proof system we consider is intuitionistic (ND); then we want to construct a proof of $A$ from the proof of $[\exists x B(x)\to  B(c)]\to A$.

Comment: @CarlMummert, thanks again, because you inspired me to make the question much more concise :)

Answer (score 1):

A "classical" proof is based on the **Theorem on Constants**: Let $T'$ be obtained from $T$ by adding new constants (but no new nonlogical axioms); then, for every formula $A$ of T and every new constant $c$, $T \vdash A(x)$ **iff** $T' \vdash A[c/x]$.

With it, it follows that if $T \vdash (\exists x B(x) \to B[c/x]) \to A$, then  $T \vdash (\exists x B(x) \to B[y/x]) \to A$, where $y$ is a new variable.

Hence, by $\exists$-introduction:

> $T \vdash \exists y \ [(\exists x B(x) \to B[y/x]) \to A].$

Now :$T \vdash \exists x B \to \exists y B[y/x]$, and thus: $T \vdash \exists y \ (\exists x B \to B[y/x])$ by the prenex operations.

Finally, by *modus ponens*:

> > $T \vdash A$.

*Unfortuantely, the "prenex operation" step is not allowed in intuitionistic logic*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

However I now realized that I should have been more specific, because you skipped precisely the part I was missing. So how would one translate those misterious "prenex operations" to an actual proof **in intuitionistic Natural Deduction**, that from $T \vdash \exists x B \to \exists y B[y/x]$ it follows that $T \vdash \exists y \ (\exists x B \to B[y/x])$?

I mean I'm worried that these prenex operations may hide some 'classicality' and therefore I'd like to see this proof using the rules of Natural Deduction, which my intuitionistic sense trusts.

Comment: Actually my doubts are quite correct:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Intuitionistic_logic